# Как правильно хранит даты в базе?

Tags: postgresql, время, временная-зона

Пользователи могут быть из самых разных временных зон.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно указывать тип данных `timestamptz`. И при занесении даты в базу данных, или при фильтре по дате, она должна быть в формате `Unix`. И настойка `timezone`, в конфиге `PostgreSQL`, должна иметь значение `UTC`.

А данные о времени с сервера будут идти в формате `Unix` (и с БД на сервер тоже), клиент будет их сам переводить в нужную временную зону. Также и с клиента данные на сервер будут приходить в формате `Unix`. И когда нужно сделать `insert` с полем со временем, в хранимке, я делаю так - `SELECT to_timestamp(1620827352)`. И в случае если используется `DEFAULT` значение, оно должно давать дату в `UTC`?

Comment: Всё зависит от задачи. Не зря же существует несколько вариантов хранения даты и времени в postgres. И с зоной, и без зоны. Всё правильно.

Comment: @Sergey например если задача - это какой-то DOTO list, которым могут пользоваться люди из самых разных временных зон, но там есть функция подлиться списком, и человек с которым поделились списком  из другой временной зоны должен видеть время в своей зоне.
Описанное мной решение правильное?

Comment: В общем правильное, но необходимости в utc на севере нет. да и даты можно в любом другом формате передавать. Если форматы передаваемых данных будут содержать временную зону, то при записи в timestamptz она будет приведена к временной зоне сервера (если не будут - то будет считаться что они в зоне сервера). Останется только добавить перевод временной зоны сервера в зону клиента при получении данных из БД (опять же в любом удобном формате, не обязательно unix)

Comment: @Metamorphosis Наверное правильно. У меня нет шибко много времени думать над Вашей задачей. А вообще, мне бы не хотелось, чтобы кто-то на другой стороне земного шара составлял TODOlist для меня. Наверняка время исполнения поставит в своём поясе (учитывая, что всё больше людей верят в то, что земля плоская, то о временных зонах и подавно не знают:). Из-за таких бестолочей кому-то придётся работать по ночам:)